# Laser printer: What can be the cause of thin printing on one edge of the paper when it's not the cartridge that is bad?

Tags: printing, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

My laser printer has started to print thinly on one of the long edges of the paper. I thought it was toner problem, but after changing to another full cartridge (that has been shaken and turned) the problem persists.

I've found a number of things that can cause this problem, among them toner not being evenly distributed in the cartridge, but all causes I've found are related to the toner and should not persist after changing the cassette.

The problem appeared when I changed cartridge, so at first I was sure it was the toner, but as said I have now tried with two different cartridges (both from the same manufacturer of reconditioned cartridges). If the problem has something to do with the cartridge, it has to be a problem that is present in both of them, which I think seems unlikely.

Also tried to change the chip on the new cartridge for the one on the older cartridge that didn't print thin, but this doesn't help.

So, my question is: **What can the the cause of thin printing on one of the long edges of the paper (the side most far from the connector on the side of the photo conductor drum)?**

The printer is a HP Laserjet 1320.

**EDIT:** A half-way-test (feeding paper manually, opening lid when paper is almost fully inside the printer, remove cartridge and look at unfused print) shows the same defect, so I guess that means that it's either the cartridge (which should be more or less ruled out since I tried two of them) or the transfer roller -- at least not the fuser. I know the transfer roller got lots of toner on it when I changed the cartridge. I has since been cleaned, but the problem persists anyway.

Comment: Could be dirty rollers or fuser needs replacing. I would consider getting it serviced by a local printer service person.

Comment: Get a drum & fuser service kit, people often just replace the toner and neglect the fuser and/or drum.

Comment: @John, could you elaborate a bit on how it could be caused by dirty rollers?

Comment: Use over time, some ink comes off paper and causes the rollers to get dirty. Same for drum.  Need for fuser replacement can cause this.

Comment: @spikey_richie, do you mean the photoconductor drum? It's in the cartridge on the HP Laserjet 1320.

Comment: Refurb toner.. although 99% of the time, it has been one of the comments listed above..  It could also be a dirty corona wire.  [Not for the average joe to fix depending on the printer](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/HP+LaserJet+1320+Teardown/45671) .. see step 49.  The picture sucks though as you can barely see the corona wire in the right of the frame.

Comment: Interesting @SeñorCMasMas! But this problem arose when the transfer roller got toner on it. Is there any way that toner spill inside of the machine could get to the corona wire and mess it up you mean?

Comment: "problem arose when the transfer roller got toner on it. Is there any way that toner spill inside of the machine "  I believe this can happen. That is one reason I suggest getting the printer serviced.

Answer (score 0):

Since I know know the rare reason for my problem I'll describe it here, and also make a summary of the clever suggestions I got as comments:

**The actual (very rare problem) of my particular case:**

The two refurbished cartridges I tried were of a different brand and a slightly different construction than the ones I used before. This makes them fit just about 2 mm bad on the left side, due to a damaged piece of plastic leader inside of my printer. I can get them to print good if I stuff a little bit of rag or a wedge so that the cartridge gets correctly seated.

**Some other reasons this problem would arise (excluding anything with the cartridge itself:**

- Dirty/bad transfer roller: Wipe it clean and be careful not to get hand fat on it. Might even clean it with ethanol.
- Dirty corona wire: The thorns of the wire can be seen through a small slit behind the transfer roller on the 1320. Use a mirror and check that there's no dirt in the slit and that you can see the piece of metal with the  spikes all the way through the slit.
- Fuser problem: Do a half-way test (feed paper manually, open lid when paper is inside the machine and remove cartridge, look at the paper and see if the defect is there on the unfused print). If the defect is visible on the unfused print the fuser it not the problem.